# Passing validation error from one Property to another Property

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a class called Person like below which is validated using Fluent Validation:

***Note***: I have Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in Person Class but for simplicity I have not shown here, so that my code looks simple enough.

```
public class Person : ObjectBase
{
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
    {
        public PersonValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Age).GreaterThan(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the ViewModel :

```
public Class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        NewPerson = new Person();
    }

    private Person _newPerson;
    public Person NewPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _newPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_newPerson != value)
            {
                _newPerson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => NewPerson();
            }
        }
    }

    public string AgeString
    {
        get
        {
            return NewPerson.Age.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
            {
                NewParty.Age = 0;
            }
            else if(NewPerson.Age.ToString() != value)
            {
                int age = 0;
                bool canParse = Int32.TryParse(value, out age);

                if(canParse)
                    NewParty.Age = age;
                else
                    NewParty.age = 0;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(() => AgeString);

        }
    }

}
```

In View:

```
<Window ..........>
    <Textbox Text = {Binding NewPerson.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true} />
    <Textbox Text = {Binding AgeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true} />
</Window>
```

Now as you can see in above XAML, my Second Textbox is not Binding to NewPerson.Age but instead it binds to AgeString.

Now some of you may ask me why I am doing this?
I am doing this because if I bind my textbox to NewPerson.Age then I cannot validate it when textBox is kept empty by the user. So, I have to bind this textbox to string property.

Anyways, my textbox is bound to AgeString Property. When user enters any garbage value, It shows zero. That's great.

Look back to the Person class and its validations. I have validated Age Proerty to be greater than 0. Now I want to do same for AgeString Property.

So, my question is how to Pass this validation error from NewPerson.Age to AgeString property????

**Update:**

As suggested in the first comment, I have used Value Converter instead of a different property altogether.

Here is my updated ViewModel:

```
public Class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        NewPerson = new Person();
        SetTo18Command = new RelayCommand(SetTo18());
    }

    public RelayCommand SetTo18Command {get;set;}

    private Person _newPerson;
    public Person NewPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _newPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_newPerson != value)
            {
                _newPerson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => NewPerson();
            }
        }
    }    

    private void SetTo18()
    {
        NewPerson.Age = 18;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window ..........>

    <Textbox Text = "{Binding NewPerson.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" />
    <Textbox Text = "{Binding NewPerson.Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}" />

    <Button Command="{Binding SetTo18Command}" Content="Set to 18" />

</Window>
```

When I click on Reset button, it will set the Age of NewPerson to 18.

Here is my ValueConverter:

```
public class StringToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return 0;

        int output = 0;
        bool canParse = Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out output);

        if (canParse)
            return output;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

This works fine. But there is 1 small error.

When I set Age of Person to 0 in the textbox and then I Click on SetTo18 Button, the Value of textbox changes to 18, but still I continue to see errored red border around the textbox.

Here is my Validation Class which Implements IDataErrorInfo:

```
public abstract class ObjectBase : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public ObjectBase()
    {
        _Validator = GetValidator();
        Validate();
    }

    protected bool _IsDirty = false;
    protected IValidator _Validator = null;

    protected IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> _ValidationErrors = null;
    protected virtual IValidator GetValidator()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [NotNavigable]
    public IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> ValidationErrors
    {
        get { return _ValidationErrors; }
        set { }
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        if (_Validator != null)
        {
            ValidationResult results = _Validator.Validate(this);
            _ValidationErrors = results.Errors;
        }
    }

    [NotNavigable]
    public virtual bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ValidationErrors != null && _ValidationErrors.Count() > 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

            if (_ValidationErrors != null && _ValidationErrors.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (ValidationFailure validationError in _ValidationErrors)
                {
                    if (validationError.PropertyName == columnName)
                        errors.AppendLine(validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return errors.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First rule One Time One Place.  You don't need agestring because you already have age in the Person class.  Simply use a converter to convert it from int to string and back again.   Google WPF Converters.

Comment: @JohnPeters Thank you. That works fine. But I have got another problem while working with that value converter. I will just edit my question with necessary data.

Comment: @JohnPeters Thank you for the answer and sorry for the above comment. I have got it to work by calling OnPropertyChanged for NewPerson. That's it. Can you please post your comment as answer???